# How to retrieve all folders in a document library using java script or spservices

Tags: 2013, javascript, document-library, spservices

I have created one document library,in that library i created some folders.
How can i retrieve all folders in a particular doc lib using java script.Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Make a GET request to the following URL, It will return all folders

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + libraryRelativeUrl + "')/Folders?$select=Name,ServerRelativeUrl
```

## Using jQuery

```
function getFolders(libraryRelativeUrl) {

    var queryUrl = "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + libraryRelativeUrl + "')/Folders?$select=Name,ServerRelativeUrl";
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + queryUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

`libraryRelativeUrl` should be a relative **URL**. Let say library name is **XXX**, then value will be

```
var libraryRelativeUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + 'XXX';
```

Now call the function as below:

```
getFolders(libraryRelativeUrl);
```

## No jQuery in your page!! No problem!!

Use `XMLHttpRequest()`

```
function getFolders(libraryRelativeUrl) {

    var queryUrl = "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + libraryRelativeUrl + "')/Folders?$select=Name,ServerRelativeUrl";

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("GET", _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + queryUrl);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var response = xmlhttp.responseText;

                console.log(response.d.results);

            } else {
                alert('Error: ' + xmlhttp.statusText)
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: Using rest api i dont no how to retrieve,plz send me full code